# Add new column in responses(Swagger-ui)

Tags: json, swagger, swagger-ui, swagger-2.0

I am using [Swagger-ui](http://swagger.io/swagger-ui/) for the api documentation, when i come to responses i want to add a new column of any name in every response,[image] screen shot is attached, highlighted text is ok, i want to add a new column at place of the circle.
My response JSON is

```
 "responses" : {
           "400" : {
              "description" : "Invalid ID Supplied"
           },
           "404" : {
              "description" : "Order not found"
           }
        }
```

> how to add new column in it?

**Is there any way type of Intellisense provided for Swagger-ui JSON?**

Answer (score 4):

You can extend the API Response objects coming off of your API endpoints only [as far as the specification goes](http://swagger.io/specification/#responseObject). In order to display that in the UI, though, you would have to fork the [UI project](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui) and do as you please. Currently the UI [does not seem to be extensible](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/master/dist/swagger-ui.js) at that point (look for the table headers in the file).