# How to add a new parameter in swagger ui?

Tags: swagger, swagger-ui, swagger-2.0

Is it possible to add a new parameter in the highlighted area of swagger ui?if 
 yes, then how?

[image]

Comment: Just add it to the endpoint as a parameter to your controler method and it will apear there

Comment: "New parameter" - meaning query/header parameter? Or a new column in the table?

Comment: a new column in the table

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add new column in responses(Swagger-ui)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35014457/add-new-column-in-responsesswagger-ui)

Comment: Your question is way to broad...  Swaggger-UI is open source and hosted in GitHub, get the code there and if you get stuck with something specific ask here